# Why does change the height of an EditText when modifying its background?

Tags: android, android-edittext, height

I have an editText in the following way:

```html
<EditText
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/edtNombreActDetallesProductoServicio"
  android:maxLines="1"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:padding="14px"
  android:layout_marginLeft="8px"
  android:layout_marginRight="8px"
  android:layout_marginBottom="8px"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
  android:textColor="@android:color/black"
  android:background="@drawable/edit_text_redondeado"/>
```

I modified your backGround in the following way:

```js
private void habilitarControles(boolean estado){
    Drawable fondo = null;
    if (true == estado){
         fondo = (Drawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edit_text_redondeado);
    }
    else{
         fondo = (Drawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edit_text_redondeado_deshabilitado);
   }
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
           edtNombreActDetallesProductoServicio.setBackground(fondo);
   }
```

Where:

edit_text_redondeado:

```html
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
                <stroke android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:width="2dp" />
                <corners android:radius="7dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </selector>
```

and edit_text_redondeado_deshabilitado:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@color/colorGrisClaro"/>
                <stroke android:color="@color/colorBlanco" android:width="2dp" />
                <corners android:radius="7dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </selector>
```

But when the application is run and the backGround is changed, the width of the editText is reduced in size. (The first two editText of the top)

[image]

I have tried to fix that problem after changing the backGround by programming dynamically. (ie re-set the width values equal to MATCH_PARENT and height equal to WRAP_CONTENT)

But the problem persists.

Any idea or suggestion is welcome